# Ruby regex to extract match_group value?

Tags: ruby, regex

I have two questions about regex.

1. The match string is:

   ```
   "FuR6UcUiduzPyenxCSzZbDXTge3f3t9ufA, user_email=admin@example.com"
   ```

   When extracting the `user_email` value, my regexp is:

   ```
   \s+(?<email_from_header>\S+)
   ```

   and the match group value is:

   ```
   (space)user_email=admin@example.com"
   ```

   What do I use to omit the first `(space)` char and the last `"` quote?
2. When extracting the token, my regex is:

   ```
   AUTH-TOKEN\s+(?<auth_token>\S+)
   ```

   and the match group value is:

   ```
   FuR6UcUiduzPyenxCSzZbDXTge3f3t9ufA,
   ```

   What do I use to delete that last trailing comma `,`?

Comment: Are the `"`s at the beginning and the end escaped double quote characters within the string? Or, are they part of the string literal? If it is the former, it is mysterious why they are not escaped in your description. If it is the latter, your attempt to try to omit the `"` does not make sense at all.

Comment: Is this Ruby regex? If so, why is it tagged "nsregularexpression"? It is confusing. Or, is it not?

Comment: why `AUTH-TOKEN\s+(?<auth_token>\S+)` isn't matches the starting `"`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Your regex would be,

   ```
   \s+\K(?<email_from_header>[^"]*)
   ```

   Use `\K` switch to discard the previously matched characters. And use not character class to match any character not of `"` zero or more times.
2. Your regex would be,

   ```
   AUTH-TOKEN\s+(?<auth_token>[^,]*)
   ```

   `[^,]*` it would match any character not of `,` zero or more times.

Answer (score 2):

If your string has embedded double-quotes:

```
str[/^"(.+),/, 1] # => "FuR6UcUiduzPyenxCSzZbDXTge3f3t9ufA"
str[/^"(.+?),/, 1] # => "FuR6UcUiduzPyenxCSzZbDXTge3f3t9ufA"
str[/^"([^,]+),/, 1] # => "FuR6UcUiduzPyenxCSzZbDXTge3f3t9ufA"

str = '"FuR6UcUiduzPyenxCSzZbDXTge3f3t9ufA, user_email=admin@example.com"'
str # => "\"FuR6UcUiduzPyenxCSzZbDXTge3f3t9ufA, user_email=admin@example.com\""

str[/(user_email=.+)"/, 1] # => "user_email=admin@example.com"
str[/(user_email=[^"]+)"/, 1] # => "user_email=admin@example.com"
str[/user_email=([^"]+)"/, 1] # => "admin@example.com"
match = str.match(/(?<user_email>user_email=(?<addr>.+))"/)
match # => #<MatchData "user_email=admin@example.com\"" user_email:"user_email=admin@example.com" addr:"admin@example.com">
match['user_email'] # => "user_email=admin@example.com"
match['addr'] # => "admin@example.com"
```

If it doesn't:

```
str = 'FuR6UcUiduzPyenxCSzZbDXTge3f3t9ufA, user_email=admin@example.com'
str # => "FuR6UcUiduzPyenxCSzZbDXTge3f3t9ufA, user_email=admin@example.com"

str[/^(.+),/, 1] # => "FuR6UcUiduzPyenxCSzZbDXTge3f3t9ufA"
str[/^(.+?),/, 1] # => "FuR6UcUiduzPyenxCSzZbDXTge3f3t9ufA"
str[/^([^,]+),/, 1] # => "FuR6UcUiduzPyenxCSzZbDXTge3f3t9ufA"

str[/(user_email=.+)/, 1] # => "user_email=admin@example.com"
str[/(user_email=(.+))/, 2] # => "admin@example.com"
str[/user_email=(.+)/, 1] # => "admin@example.com"
```

Or, having more regex fun:

```
match = str.match(/(?<user_email>user_email=(?<addr>.+))/)
match # => #<MatchData "user_email=admin@example.com" user_email:"user_email=admin@example.com" addr:"admin@example.com">
match['user_email'] # => "user_email=admin@example.com"
match['addr'] # => "admin@example.com"
```

Regular expressions are a very rich language, and you can write something in many ways usually. The problem then becomes maintaining the pattern as the program "matures". I recommend starting simply, and expanding the pattern as the needs dictate. Don't start complex hoping to find a working solution, because that usually doesn't work; Getting a complex pattern to work immediately often fails.